# Ccc Background position x calcular

Tags: javascript, html, css

Me estoy comiendo la cabeza con una cosa que me gustaria saber si pueden ayudarme . Gracias antes de todo.

Resulta ser que estoy creando el css de una pagina de "ruleta" tipo ruleta de csgo pero tengo un problema y es que basicamente quiero posicionar la imagen en el centro usando "background position x" Para luego en js en funcion de lo que salga mover la ruleta para realizar dicha animacion.

El problema resulta que al hacer mas o menos grande la imagen de la ruleta que mostrara que ha tocado ps me da "background position" distinto al en el que estaba trabajando antes que seria a 1360px . Entonces queria saber si hay alguna manera de calcular dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla y que la imagen quede justo en medio como sale en el code pen
Da igual con el codigo que sea pero que lo haga con el background position y tambien poder realizar animaciones con esto para mover la "ruleta" y mostrar el "ganador"

El resto ya lo hago yo pero me estoy comiendo la cabeza con eso ya que no trabajo css y no se me ocurre ninguna solucion aparte de hacer un codigo para cada tamaño etc etc

```css
.pad{
  width:1360px;
  margin:auto;
}
.ruleta::before{
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/qOck6S5.png);
    width: 14px;
    height: 115px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
.ruleta{
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/60X89Ha.png);
    background-position-x: -64px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
p{
  font-size:24px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pad">
  <div class="ruleta">
  </div>
</div>

<p>Quiero que quede con el color verde totalmente en el centro en los distintos tamaños</p>
```

[Codepen original](https://codepen.io/yosoypollito/pen/WNeYzPP?fbclid=IwAR3GzjDSp83BR-XsWTlPaWw243y6_MY1lUpz562LJTkv-8DA_LO-1CS7GlA)

Comment: ¿Podrías usar imágenes en los `background` que podamos ver? Ni aquí ni en el *codepen* se visualizan.

Comment: Listo ya cambie las imagenes , deberian ver se ahora

Comment: ¿Quieres que el verde se vea siempre en el centro independientemente de la resolución?

Comment: Si en el centro , pero la gracia es que usare un codigo js para hacer que se mueva y salga el "color ganador" y usaria el "position" para mover la ruleta en js

Answer (score 4):

Usando la propiedad `background-position:center;` en el `<div>` que tiene la ruleta, harías que la imagen permaneciese siempre centrada en cualquier resolución, ya que al achicarse su contenedor mantendría el punto de referencia en el centro.

```css
.pad{
  width:400px;
  margin:auto;
}
.ruleta::before{
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/qOck6S5.png);
    width: 14px;
    height: 115px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: -7px;
}
.ruleta{
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/60X89Ha.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
p{
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size:24px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:50px;
  }
  
  .pad-escritorio {
    width: 1250px;
  }
  
  .pad-tablet {
    width: 650px;
  }
  
  .pad-movil {
    350px;
  }
  
  @media (max-device-width: 1300px) {
    .pad-tablet, .pad-movil {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  
  @media (max-device-width: 700px) {
    .pad-escritorio, .pad-movil {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  
  @media (max-device-width: 400px) {
    .pad-escritorio, .pad-tablet {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="pad pad-escritorio">
  <div class="ruleta">
  </div>
</div>

<!--<div class="pad pad-tablet">
  <div class="ruleta">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pad pad-movil">
  <div class="ruleta">
  </div>
</div>-->

<p>Quiero que quede con el color verde totalmente en el centro en los distintos tamaños</p>
```

Comment: Si estaria posicionado en el centro , pero usare el position para "animar" el giro, y necesito que el pequeño marcador / indicador que sale quede en el centro del verde siempre.

Comment: Aunque luego uses el `background-position` para animar la ruleta, entiendo que el punto de partida siempre tiene que ser el icono verde en el centro. ¿Correcto? Y que cuando hagas girar la ruleta en el centro acabará un icono seleccionado aleatoriamente, no de nuevo el verde. ¿Voy bien encaminado?

Comment: Exacto pero si te fijas en el codigo que me pasaste el indicador esta un poco a la derecha del centro del icono verde. Y lo que quiero es que al cargar la pagina salga en todos los tamaños el icono verde centrado con el marcador asi sea a 300px el tamaño del div

Comment: Modifiqué un poco el **CSS** para hacer que el marcador coincida también con el centro del contenedor. Achiqué el tamaño del contenedor para que veas como si visualizaría en pantallas más pequeñas y que permanece todo perfectamente en su centro ^^

Comment: Vale ya se que soy molesto , Pero aplicale un position-x = -100px quedaria entre la ficha 2 y 13 , si ahora yo cambio el tamaño del `.pad` a 500px sin cambiar el position x el marcador pasaria a quedar casi en el centro de la ficha/icono 13.

Comment: Ahora he entendido lo que quieres decir. No sé si existe una manera de hacer lo que quieres. La única que se me ocurre ahora mismo es tener diferentes `<div>` con tamaños en píxeles fijos y mostrar u ocultar con *mediaqueries* estos div para dejar visible el que tengas preparado para el rango de tamaño de dispositivo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98890/discussion-between-daniel-alejandro-iglesias-ferm-and-phpmyguel).

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien lo que deseas lograr, es centrar tanto la imagen de `background` como la imagen del marcador, de tal forma que sin importar el tamaño de la pantalla, siempre queden centradas al cargar la página. Además, las mismas deben permanecer centradas al cambiar (ajustar) el tamaño de la pantalla.

En tu código veo que has colocado tamaños fijos para los contenedores `div`:

```
.pad{
  width:1360px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Y por los comentarios parece que te sugieren usar [`@media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) para manejar el comportamiento según los diferentes tamaños de pantalla de dispositivos.

Sin embargo, creo que el criterio que aplicas no es el adecuado, ya que al establecer un tamaño (ancho) fijo para un elemento y al realizar un ajuste en el ancho de la pantalla o `viewport`, el elemento será más grande o más pequeño, rompiendo toda característica de [Diseño Web Adaptable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dise%C3%B1o_web_adaptable).

En el siguiente código establezco el ancho de los elementos (`div.pad` y `div.ruleta`) a un valor de 100% (también puedes colocarlos en `auto`). De esta forma, ambos elementos tendrán el tamaño del elemento padre (en mi ejemplo `body` es elemento padre de `div.pad` y a su vez `div.pad` es el elemento padre de `div.ruleta`).

Otro atributo que he establecido en el elemento `div.pad` es el de [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), el cual es puesto como [`border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Valores), esto con la finalidad de evitar posibles problemas al momento de realizar cambios sobre el borde, relleno o contenido del elemento `div.pad`.

Por último, en el elemento `div.ruleta`, he establecido el atributo `background-repeat` con un valor de `repeat-x`, lo cual te permitirá realizar la animación que estás buscando con el atributo `backgground-position-x`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pad{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ruleta::before{
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    height: 137px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/qOck6S5.png);
    width: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
.ruleta {
    text-align: center;
    height: 137px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/60X89Ha.png);
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.legend {
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pad">
  <div class="ruleta" id="ruleta"></div>
</div>
<div class="legend">
  <p>.pad width: 100%;
</div>
```

Si varías el tamaño de la página, las imágenes siempre quedarán centradas en la misma.

Espero que sea lo que estabas buscando.

Comment: El verdadero problema de todo es que quiero saber la manera de que valor poner en funcion al tamaño de la pantalla del usuario ya que si aplicas un `background-position-x : 500px` con la ventana EXPANDIDA a 1080p por ejemplo se movera el fondo hasta cierto punto. Sin mover el position-x achicas la ventana a cualquier tamaño el Indicador no quedaria marcando la misma pieza o ficha que cuando estaba en 1080p eso es lo que quiero evitar. Aun no se como <3 . Esto lo habia logrado de una manera distinta pero funcionaba casi "igual"